# How would I create a "back button" submit to return a previous partial view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I've googled my heart out for this.  In asp.net mvc I have a form that loads partial views.  I'd like to put a back button on this form so the user can go back to the previous partial view.  (not a browser back button, but a input type submit back button.) It needs to retain the information in the previous partial view which i already have in session.

Answer (score 0):

Put the name of the partial view in a hidden field.

And when you post back, render than partial view.

So paraphrasing you would render a hidden field in the form with the name of your partial. Then model bind it into a post method.

Call the same view from your post method, but this time render that partial coming in on from the hidden field.

Comment: Do you by chance have any code? I am pretty new to all this.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve this problem without using tools such as History.js. I added a method to _Layout called Navigate too, this does my navigation to the partial views.  These calls are saved in a stack so I know what was navigated (I'm saving the actual ActionLink text).

When the user click Back, I pop the stack twice, thus giving me the previous page, and then I use NavigateTo to go to this page.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by jquery, Put a button on your form and call the following jquery function on it..

```
 function BacktoPartial() {

        $.get('/URL to your Partial View',
        function (data) {
            $('#Yourdiv --Where you are rendering partial view').html(data);
        })
    .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    });
    }
```

> **Updated Code Sample:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#btnBack").click(function (event) {
        BacktoPartial();
    });
function BacktoPartial() {

    $.get('/URL to your Partial View',
    function (data) {
        $('#Yourdiv --Where you are rendering partial view').html(data);
    })
.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
});
}
</script>
```

Now i am using here anchor and giving its button shape; you may add button instead of anchor to your view, if you want. Here is the sample code:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" id="btnBack" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="icon-search icon-white"></i>BACK</a>
```

Comment: How would I call the function on the back button?